# How to delete new array in react native object

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting, arraylist

I have following array

```
[{

        "games1": [{
            "playername": "1"
        }]
    },
    {

        "games2": [{
                "playername": "1"
            },
            {
                "playername": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to delete games2 from the array how to do this
I want this type of output

```
[{

        "games1": [{
            "playername": "1"
        }]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filter to filter what you want to keep.

Like this:

```
const arr = [
            {
                games1: [
                    {
                        playername: '1',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                games2: [
                    {
                        playername: '1',
                    },
                    {
                        playername: '2',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ]

// keep games1

const newArr = arr.filter((r) => r.games1)
console.log(newArr)

        // remove games2, keep others
const newArr2 = arr.filter((r) => !r.games2)
console.log(newArr2)
```

output would be

```
[
    {
        "games1": [
            {
                "playername": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: @MohitJain  Try this `const newArr2 = arr.filter((r) => !r.games2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const NewArray = array.filter((item) => item !== "games2");

console.log(NewArray)
```

Comment: `games2` is the name of the key, not the value itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
 let final = x.filter(x=>{
     let c = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(x)
    return c!="games2"
 })
```

here the output of the 'final' is :

```
[{

        "games1": [{
            "playername": "1"
        }]
    }
}]
```

[image: output]